# Result of form.data.get is None

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

forms.py:

```
class DealForm(BaseForm, ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Deal

    values = django_forms.ChoiceField(widget = django_forms.Select, required=False, choices=[(1, "111"), (2, "222"), (3, "333")])
```

views.py:

```
class CreateDealView(DealBaseView, CreateView):
    template_name = 'deal.html'
    model = Deal
    form_class = DealForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(CreateDealView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = kwargs.get('form')
        print form.data.get('values') # prints "None"
```

How to pass field data from form to view?

EDIT:
I reformulate the question.
I need to pass pre-set choices from form to view and then to template. How to do this?

Comment: And what are you expecting it to print?

Comment: Print is only for debugging. I want to pass list of choices to view and then to template, but somewhere in the middle it is lost.

Comment: What is lost? `form.data` is the data that has been submitted to the form (pre-validation), not the choices.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to populate a field with the choices to pick from? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

views.py:

```
deal.setdefault('values', form.fields['values'].choices or '')
```

template:

```
    <select id="val" name="value_list">
    {% for id, val in deal.values %}
        <option value="{{id}}"
        {% if val == current_val %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
            {{val}}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the different set of choices than the ones defined in your form, set the choices on your field once the form is instantiated:

```
class CreateDealView(DealBaseView, CreateView):
    template_name = 'deal.html'
    model = Deal
    form_class = DealForm

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(CreateDealView, self).get_form(form_class)
        choices = [('some', 1), ('other', 2), ('choices', 3)]
        form.fields['values'].choices = choices
        return form
```

However, if you meant the original choices on your field, you don't need to do anything, they are already in your form.